# ERC20 Transfer doesn’t work

Tags: erc-20

I am new to smart contracts, trying to make an NFT Raffle contract. I wanted to allow people to buy with chain currency (MATIC) and a custom ERC20 token. I got it to work with main chain currencies but it doesn’t work with ERC20.

The error I get:

`missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string`

```
function buyEntryERC20(uint256 _numOfEntries) public payable {
    require(allowERC20, "Buying tickets with ERC20 is disabled");
    require(raffleStatus, "Raffle is not started");
    require(
        _numOfEntries + totalEntries <= maxEntries,
        "You cannot exceed the max entries limit"
    );
    IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(msg.sender, tokenCost * _numOfEntries);

    require(
        IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender) >=
            tokenCost * _numOfEntries,
        "Insufficient Tokens"
    );

    // Transfer tokens from sender to contract
    IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(address(this), tokenCost * _numOfEntries);

    // rest of the function remains the same
    entryCount[msg.sender] += _numOfEntries;
    totalEntries += _numOfEntries;
    if (!isPlayer(msg.sender)) {
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _numOfEntries; i++) {
        playerSelector.push(msg.sender);
    }
    emit NewEntry(msg.sender);
    if (totalEntries >= maxEntries) {
        endRaffle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the approving mechanism.

Your function should transfer the token amount from the msg.sender to this contract, but it's not happening.

In this line:
`IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(address(this), tokenCost * _numOfEntries);`
this contract will be the `msg.sender` inside the token contract, which means this contract is transferring the tokens from itself to itself.

Now comes the real way to do it. You will have to use `transferFrom` function:

```
IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenCost * _numOfEntries)
```

Before that, the user needs to approve the tokens manually, which means this line:

```
IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(msg.sender, tokenCost * _numOfEntries);
```

is not correct, as your contract is approving the `msg.sender`, which should be the opposite.
The sender needs to manually call the approve function with this contract's address.

Comment: That worked! I just got a little mixed up within arguments + didn't know I need to call approve manually. ty!

Comment: amazing, just remember whenever any contract calls another contract it becomes the `msg.sender`. The only exception is `delegatecall`, which is different.